# Cannot insert empty string in oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

i am trying to insert data into one of my table.

```
insert into t_transaction_query_log
    (log_id,
     posting_id,
     fee_id,
     fee_status,
     fee_type,
     pay_mode,
     accounting_date,
     policy_id,
     money_id,
     finish_time,
     source_type,
     fee_amount,
     cr_seg,
     dr_seg,
     product_id' || v_insert_str_cr_seg ||
                  v_insert_str_dr_seg || ')       
    select s_transaction_query_log__lg_id.nextval,
           tg.je_posting_id,
           tg.fee_id,
           tg.fee_status,
           tg.fee_type,
           60,
           tg.accounting_date,
           tg.policy_id,
           tg.currency_id,
           trunc(sysdate,
                 ''dd''),
           2,
           tg.fee_amount,' ||v_str_cr_seg
                   || ',' || v_str_dr_seg || ',
           tg.product_id' || v_insert_str_cr_seg ||
                  v_insert_str_dr_seg || '
      from t_ri_fee_gl tg
     where tg.posted = ''Y''
```

i have declared v_str_cr_seg,v_str_dr_seg as empty strings i.e v_str_dr_seg varchar(50)='';

before executing this query i am able to append some values to these two strings
but in case there is no change in these strings from the declaration
i am getting the computed query as

```
 insert into t_transaction_query_log
    (log_id,
     posting_id,
     fee_id,
     fee_status,
     fee_type,
     pay_mode,
     accounting_date,
     policy_id,
     money_id,
     finish_time,
     source_type,
     fee_amount,
     cr_seg,
     dr_seg,
     product_id)       
    select s_transaction_query_log__lg_id.nextval,
           tg.je_posting_id,
           tg.fee_id,
           tg.fee_status,
           tg.fee_type,
           60,
           tg.accounting_date,
           tg.policy_id,
           tg.currency_id,
           trunc(sysdate,
                 'dd'),
           2,
           tg.fee_amount, , ,
           tg.product_id
      from t_ri_fee_gl tg
     where tg.posted = 'Y'
```

which in turn results in missing expression error.
i have tried using nvl function as

```
nvl(v_str_cr_seg, '') and `nvl(v_str_cr_seg, null)`
```

but still i am getting the same error

how can i insert even though v_str_cr_seg and v_str_dr_seg are unchanged
i.e empty strings `''`

Answer (score 0):

Ora DB:
empty string = null
[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements005.htm)

Note:
Oracle Database currently treats a character value with a length of zero as null. However, this may not continue to be true in future releases, and Oracle recommends that you do not treat empty strings the same as nulls.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an insert Statement in the middle of a PL/SQL Routine, then you would not string concatenate. It would rather look like this

```
       tg.fee_amount, v_str_cr_seg, v_str_dr_seg
```

But something from your question tells me that you are composing a string that you want to `execute immediate`.

In this case you have to make sure you are giving quotes:

```
       tg.fee_amount,''' ||v_str_cr_seg
               || ''',''' || v_str_dr_seg || ''',
       tg.product_id''' || v_insert_str_cr_seg ||
              v_insert_str_dr_seg || '''
```

You need to escape the single quote (`'`) with two quotes in a row (`''`)

But if your strings already come with quotes around it unless null you may want to work with nvl this way

```
       tg.fee_amount,' ||nvl(v_str_cr_seg,'''''')
               || ',' || nvl(v_str_dr_seg,'''''') || ',
```

Comment: Yes i am composing this string to use with execute immediate

Comment: Then this should work. You have to make sure you do not have a `, , ,` but `'', '', ''`. You could also have a `null, null, null`. Maybe you prepare `v_str_cr_seg` etc. before that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using chr(0) instead of ''. Null character is a sign of the end of a string.